# Rule of Thumb on OS Free Space

Tags: postgresql, linux, storage

This may be a difficult question to answer, but I have a PostgreSQL database running on a Linux server with 1.3 TB of storage.  I'm currently at 73% utilization of storage space with a slow but steady increase of about 1% a month with the occasional uptick due to a large table being added.

I'm taking into consideration that:

1. PostgreSQL needs some headroom for queries, MVCC
2. The operating system needs some headroom, for whatever it is operating systems do
3. Because Linux doesn't "defrag" in the way we think of with Windows, I need to take into consideration that as space shrinks, contiguous space will be at a premium, which will likely impact performance of both the OS and the DB
4. Things I haven't thought of

My question is at what point do I need to request more space?  My thought was when I hit 80% I should ask for more, but I want to have a good balance of foresight and responsible use of department funds.

Does anyone have a gut feel for at what point I need to start thinking about increasing my allocation?

Oh, and before anyone tells me that space is cheap -- it's not, not when you work in corporate America.  Space is funded based on service agreements, backup/recovery, etc and does not equal what you would pay for 1 TB of storage at Staples.

Comment: Potentially major (non-tech) factor: how long does it take between the time you make the request for more space and the time you actually get it live on the server(s)?

Comment: Also, how business critical is this system from the business side? Would it running out of space at some point hose something up and cause major business ramifications or money loss, screaming clients, etc? If so, then that alone should be justification enough for your corporation to spend the money on expanding the disks to allocate more space based on your recommendation and you trying to be proactive.  Get someone from the business side on board that's important and then present your proposal to whoever else may need to agree on the cost being justified.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...  I'm actually on the business side and have control of the budget -- but my performance is rated on how I manage the budget, so I care!  I realize I have no business part-timing as a DBA, but that's a separate matter.  The data is extremely business critical.  We run our business off of this server.  As far as how long it takes to get the space...  I'm not sure.  You two scared me enough that I just requested another 300 GB today.  For future reference, I'd still like to know when is the "best" time.

Comment: I'm not much or a Linux or PostgreSQL admin, but with Windows and SQL Server, you'd never put the core OS and the SQL Server data and log files on the same server disk partitions in a business critical production environment but it sounds as that's how yours is configured which I assume would mean if you run out of space, the entire system comes to a halt. It sounds like you've been bench-marking your growth so based on that, it sounds like you'd know when it may get to a critical threshold. I assume you cannot ever archive any data and clear up unused space for new data reuse either?

Comment: Unix allocates space on different file systems, so running of out of "data" space is different than having my OS or the database itself run out of space.  And, the storage itself is on a SAN, so it's completely separate from the physical server.  Good points to bring up, though.

Comment: In addition to how long it takes to allocate more storage, it also depends on the impact of adding more storage. It is just a hot filesystem resize on a SAN-mounted volume? Does it require shutting down and going offline to resize a file system? Does it require stopping the system and copying the data to a new disk array? All these things are significant when planning.